# What happens if the initialization part of a for-loop is missing?

Tags: c++

While trying to understand the code below I've encountered the following question(s): What happens, as shown in the example below, if the initialization part of a for loop is missing?

```
using namespace std;

void print(int a) {
  int b;
  for (; a ; a = a/10)
    for (b = a+2; b>a; b=b-1)
      cout << b;
}

int main() 
{
  int a{10};

  print(a);  
  cout << a;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of the three statements making up the `for` control loop are optional. This came from C and makes the `for` loop structure remarkably powerful.

If the initialisation part is missing then nothing is initialised.

In your particular case `a` is passed to the function (and therefore needs to be initialised before it's passed), so it makes no sense for the `for` loop to perform further initialisation.

Note that if the condition check statement if missing then you need to control the loop exit condition yourself in the loop body. In your program that statement is the expression `a`, in other words your loop terminates when `a` is zero.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to initialize a parameter, but it might be worth pointing out that `int a; print(a);` will invoke UB.

Comment: @cigien: It's always hard to know how thorough you need to be. The behaviour of the program is also undefined for `a == INT_MAX`.

Comment: Indeed. It's not a big deal, I just thought that might be a useful point. At the moment, the phrasing does make it seem like since `a` is a parameter, there's no initialization to worry about. Which is true inside the function, so it's ok I guess :)

Comment: @cigien: Yes, it reads better with something said about the initialisation requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Well, originally, semicolon version of the for loop came from B, to which it came from somebody named Johnson (probably, Stephen Johnson from Bell Labs).